# Unable to perform load test of a hybrid mobile app on an Android phone

Tags: jmeter

I am working on designing a load test script for a hybrid Android mobile app. I have performed the following steps but still I am unable to record the network traffic in Jmeter:

1. Connected my Android phone to my laptop using a USB cable and then copied the certificate file from Jmeter's bin directory to my phone.
2. Then installed the certificate on my phone.
3. Then I added manual proxy settings on my phone by setting proxy host name = my ipv4 address, and proxy port = port set on Jmeter.
4. Then I saved the settings and then tried recording but unfortunately nothing was recorded.
5. I noticed a very weird thing that on changing the proxy settings on my phone it was no longer connected to the wifi when in fact the internet was working fine on my laptop.

Please note that my phone and my laptop are connected to the same wifi network.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot provide comprehensive answer without seeing:

- [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
- [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener results (if any)
- [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) of the Android device

So for the time being I can suggest the following checklist:

0. You didn't start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
1. The [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) of your operating system is not allowing incoming connections to port "port set on Jmeter"
2. If you want to have Internet on the Android device make sure that JMeter can connect to the Internet, if you're [using the proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) - you need to explicitly configure JMeter to use this proxy
3. For [Android 7.0](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/) and above it's required to take [extra steps](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) for recording HTTPS traffic